# can't install libc6 package

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
esrsank@PG04954:~$ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:   build-essential :

 Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev  

libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.6) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 is to be installed


 libstdc++6-4.6-dev : Depends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed


E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So how to install libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.6) instead of libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.10)

the same for ibstdc++6-4.6-dev

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

Then run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If it works, then fine.
or again try doing

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Comment: Just highlighting to others the fact that `dist-upgrade` can have wide reaching effects given it updates the kernel.

Answer (score 4):

> One possible cause of unmet dependencies could be corrupted package
>   database, and/or some packages weren’t installed properly. To fix this
>   problem, hit Alt+Ctrl+T to open terminal and try to run one of the
>   following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get clean
> ```
>
> or,
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get autoclean
> ```
>
> apt-get clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package
>   files (the .deb files). It removes everything but the lock file from
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/. apt-get
>   autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files,
>   but unlike apt-get clean, it only removes package files that can no
>   longer be downloaded, and are largely useless.
>
> One of the most basic fixes to resolve dependencies problems is to
>   run:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -f install
> ```
>
> The -f here stands for “fix broken”. Apt will attempt to correct
>   broken dependencies. If you manually installed a package that had
>   unmet dependencies, apt-get will install those dependencies, if
>   possible, otherwise it may simply remove the package that you
>   installed in order to resolve the problem.
>
> Then run:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --configure -a
> ```
>
> Then run this again:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -f install
> ```

Reference: #https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa